# Locate file in the jar

Tags: executable-jar

Here is the scenario, in the eclipse, I have a folder called "profile" in the project. I passed "profile" as a String parameter to a function, which will access the files in the "profile" folder.
When I generate a runnable Jar file and try to run, the program could not find the "profile" directory.
Does somebody know how to achieve this?

The actual code is I used a third party code, which is a language detector, and it needs to load profiles to detect language.

```
DetectorFactory.loadProfile("profile");
```

But I assume my question is not related to specific code, if I try to use plain String for new File(), the same problem will happen. Just want to know how to access directory and files in the JAR file.

Comment: Is the folder called `profile`, or `profiles`? The two are not the same. Have you added that directory as a source folder in Eclipse so that Eclipse includes the folder when building the JAR? Have you tried unzipping the JAR to see whether or not it contains that folder? We need **way** more information than you've given us. **Please** [show valid code to reproduce the problem.](http://sscce.org)

Comment: I don't know how to add the directory as a source folder, I just copy and paste that directory. I unzipped the JAR and saw the directory is contained in the JAR file.